# Show Excerpt then Previous x Number of Posts in WordPress Loop

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the excerpt of the last post made in a category and then the previous 5 posts in that category so

```
 Category Fruit
     Apples
     This is a post about apples. I love apples you know they say an apple a day keeps the doctor away. Stack overflow is the Apple of my eye its a great place to Continue Reading ->

     And a post about oranges
     And a post about grapes
     And a post about bananas
```

Comment: where do you want it to be displayed? index? archive? somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably do it. This will show The excerpt for the most recent post and the previous 4 titles after that.

```
<?php global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 0, 'category_name' => 'fruit' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $key=>$post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
 if ($key == 0) { ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a>
<?php } else { ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Feel free to ask about how to adapt it to your needs =)